# Flutter : Why build widget runs first before the initState()?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

This is my **controller.dart** file which checks if users is verified or not and then return the page according to the conditions.
My question is that why the build widget is executing first before `initState()` ? I tried to debug this code using breakpoints and noticed that `build() widget` is running first and then the `initState()`Why this is happening and how could I fix it ?

**This is my code :**

```
class _ControllerState extends State<Controller> {
  late bool auth;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (auth==false) ? Onbording() : IndexPage();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await this.checked_if_logged();
    });

  }
  Future<void> checked_if_logged() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(prefs.getBool('verified')==true){
      setState(() {
        auth = true;
      });
    }else{
      setState(() {
        auth = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This is a snapshot of my debug code where the blue line is showing that it runs first before init and because the `bool auth` is a `late` type so it throws `lateInitializationErrror` and after that initState() is called which initializes the `auth` variable which rebuild the widget and removes the error
[image]

**Update**:
I noticed that when I replace the `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_)` with just `check_if_logged()`, the `initState()` is calling first but before completion of `check_if_logged()` the build widget executes first which again throws `lateInitializationError`

Comment: The addPostFrameCallback is called after first frame is rendered. So in your case init is called then build then the callback. It's working as expected.

Comment: init is not called first, build widget called first then the init, I updated the question so you may want to read that. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to print some text like this: one print before WidgetsBinding.instance, one inside the addPostFrameCallback, and one in build method. In your case the ```check_if_logged``` is async called, but that doesn't mean that the init state is called after. The logs will clarify the order of method calls.

Comment: Good suggestion, I found that the first print statement above the WidgetBinding.instance executed then it did not waited for completion of WidgetBinding.instance and after that second print executed and then the build method and after all of that it started executing the WidgetBinding.instance . I also noticed that I had to use null check operator(!) while using WidgetBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback (there's a null check )

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you got `addPostFrameCallback` from or what you want to achieve, but this is not the way.

Your problem is, that `checked_if_logged` is `async` and there is no way to `await` an `async` method in `initState`. That is by design and there is no way around that.

The proper way to handle this is to use a `FutureBuilder` widget.

See [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)